# Can I make Calendar on OS X automatically show me more upcoming weeks when focusing on today?

Tags: macos, ical

In Calendar on OS X (I’m using Mavericks), in month view I can hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to focus on today’s date.

When I do this, Calendar shows me all weeks in the current month. Near the end of the month (like we are now), this means I see the current week, the next week, and four previous weeks.

It would be more useful if Calendar showed me the current week and the next five weeks instead — I’m not particularly interested in what I’ve done recently, but seeing what I’m doing over the next few weeks would be good.

Is there any way to change the date range Calendar shows in month view when I focus on today?

Comment: If you scroll the Today up in Month view to first line, you will see the following 5 weeks.

Comment: @Buscar웃: very true, and this is probably what I’ll end up doing, assuming there’s no way to make it do this by default.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about Automatic.

But if you just move (scroll) the today to the first line of the Month view, you will see the following 5 weeks.

Making it automatic is a problem, since the Month view is what it says. It has been set to show the month, while Today is a variable.

Comment: How do you scroll it - I have no scroll bars in Mavericks calendar in month view and scroll wheel has no effect

Comment: I use the build in trackpad two fingers scroll :)

Comment: I have a trackball or mouse :( no trackpad